How to mock/simulate Laravel JobQueued queue event in test?
I want to test multiple event listeners that listen for Laravel's built-in queue events (all the events that live in the Illuminate\Queue\Events namespace. The listeners are part of a package.
Normally, if I want to test the behaviour of an event listener, I would do something like this:

Create the event that the listener should handle.
Instantiate the event listener and call its handle method on the event.
Assert that the actions (in this example sending a notification) are executed properly.

public function test_sends_notification_to_newly_created_user(): void
{
    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $event = new UserCreated($user);

    $eventListener = $this->app->make(SendUserCreationNotification::class);
    $eventListener->handle($event);

    Notification::assertSentTo($user, WelcomeNotification::class);
}


My listener that listens to the JobQueued event:
public function handle(JobQueued $event): void
{
    $jobUuid = $event->payload()['uuid'];

    if (property_exists($event->job, 'trackableJob')) {
        $this->updater->setQueuedStatus($event->job->trackableJob, $jobUuid);
    }
}

When I try to create the JobQueued event:
public function test_updates_status_to_queued_in_database(): void
{
    $event = new JobQueued(...); // I have to manually specify the payload (don't want to do that)
}

I also tried just dispatching a job and running it but the JobQueued event never fires:
public function test_updates_status_to_queued_in_database(): void
{
    app(Dispatcher::class)->dispatch(new TrackedJob());
    
    $this->artisan('queue:work --once');
}

How do I properly create the JobQueued event, so I can test my listener?
For clarification, the setQueuedStatus() method on the updater class. Its purpose is to set the status to queued and attach the uuid, which we can then use to track it during processing.
public function setQueuedStatus(TrackableJob $trackableJob, string $jobUuid): bool
{
    $trackableJob->job_uuid = $jobUuid;

    return $trackableJob->update([
        'queued_at' => now(),
        'status' => Status::Queued,
    ]);
}

The TrackedJob class is a test job with an empty handle() method.

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/events#testing

Have you tried creating a job class that is empty (handle) so you can dispatch it on your test and test the listener? You need to add more info about what $this->updater is, you are mixing Framework stuff with your own custom stuff, so the test may be a bit ugly to produce. Ideally you would instantiate the data you need inside the JobQueued but it is ugly to do so

I have added the setQueuedStatus() method content. The TrackedJob class is a test job with an empty handle() method. I agree, I would normally create the event manually but I don't really want to create the job payload manually.

// I have to manually specify the payload (don't want to do that) -> you may not want to do that, but that's your test, so provide the fixture. later on you can do deeper integration, but start with a simple test and provide the data yourself. this also documents the understanding you had at the time of creating the test. those are often also better tests as each test should have only one reason to fail.

This (the Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessing event) counts as laravel internals. You should not be wasting your time trying to test it.
What you can test however is

Your event is dispatched when you visit an endpoint / submit a form & whatever.
Your event is dispatched on the queue you expect it to be dispatched.
Your event has your listener attached to it.
Your listener does what you think it will do.


I agree, JobProcessing is covered by Laravel tests. In this case, so is number 2 from your list. Laravel dispatches this event when a job starts processing, also covered by the framework. Number 3 is covered by one of my own test cases. Number 4 is what I am trying to test here. But in order test that I need to have a JobProcessing event that I can pass to my listener, so I can test if it does what I need it to do.

I have updated the question with an example which maybe explains better what I am trying to do.
